# LiipImageBundle proportional increase in size and ratio

Tags: symfony, liipimaginebundle

I have installed LiipImagineBundle in Symfony 2.1 and I am trying to use it for user profiles' avatars. Liip has some sorts of settings that do not allow you to resize in width and height.

```
 my_heighten:
            filters:
                relative_resize: { heighten: 60 } # Transforms 50x40 to 75x60
        my_widen:
            filters:
                relative_resize: { widen: 32 }    # Transforms 50x40 to 32x26
```

This means that If you have an image 100px*2000px, resizing in height to 120px will have a width of more than 2000px. I want to resize both portrait and landscape images to include all possible user interactions with the image upload element. I have tried to use

```
filters:
       relative_resize: { heighten: 60, widen: 60 }
```

and

```
 filters:
           relative_resize: { heighten: 60 }
           relative_resize: { widen: 60 }
```

but none of them work.

Has anyone tried anything similar ?

EDIT: I forgot to say that I need a square image 60*60 than will not be cropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
liip_imagine:
    filter_sets:
        filter_name:
            filters:
                resize:
                    size: [60, 60]
```

Only this wont crop.

Answer (score 3):

Try the `thumbnail` filter with the `inset` mode:

```
liip_imagine:
    filter_sets:
        filter_name:
            filters:
                thumbnail:
                    size: [60, 60]
                    mode: inset
```

But you should understand that you won't get a square image if the original wasn't itself square. Instead, it will be limited by `60` pixels in width or `60` pixels in height.

If you want to get a square image, you need cropping which you can get by using the `outbound` mode.

Comment: What's the difference between outbound and inset ? The bundle is great but the documentation is not very helpful..

Comment: `outbound` crops the image for it to become exactly the size you want; `inset` minimizes the image until both sides of it are less than or equal to the corresponding side size you've set.

Comment: If the size is set at `60, 60` a 300 x 400 image would be resized to 45 x 60 with the 'inset' option and resized / cropped to 60x60 with the 'outbound' option.

Comment: be aware if the image is smaller than 60x60 it may not get square with outbound. It will increase the witdth to 60 and won't touch the height if it does not become >60 after the first manipulation.